# Trying to remember a piyyut about the morning

Tags: tefilla, song-poetry

I seem to recall that there is a piyyut that lists major events that took place early in the morning, similar to the way that "Vayehi Bachatzi Halaila" (at the beginning of Nirtzah) does for things that happen at midnight.  The only ones I can identify focus exclusively on the Akeidah.  Any leads?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of this slicha https://www.sefaria.org/Selichot_Nusach_Polin%2C_Erev_Rosh_Hashana.19.1

Comment: Note the piyut you reference ויהי בחצי הלילה is really a poem from the prayers on the morning of shabbat hagadol. It's fun and thematic so many people started singing it again after the seder. (People often sing holiday themed songs even outside prayer at meals or parties.)